# Converting daily stock returns to annual returns using a panel data set in R

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a panel data set in R with daily stock returns. The data looks like:

```
company code  company name          date   daily return
           1             A    1990-09-01            0.1
           1             A    1990-09-02           0.05
           2             B    1990-09-01           0.01
           2             B    1990-09-02           0.05
```

How can I convert this data into annual stock returns for each company for each year? I tried converting the data into an `xts` object and tried to use `Return.annualized` function but it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work" when you tried to use `xts` package?

Comment: i get the error: Error in periodicity(R) : can not calculate periodicity of 1 observation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you annual returns for each company for each year (where I've called your sample data frame `dat`):

```
library(lubridate) 
library(dplyr)

dat$date = as.Date(dat$date)
dat$year = year(dat$date)

dat %>% group_by(company_name, year) %>%
  summarise(annual_return = prod(1 + daily_return, na.rm=TRUE) - 1)

  company_name year annual_return
1            A 1990        0.1550
2            B 1990        0.0605
```

Comment: I am getting NA values for some companies for some years although the daily return data exists, what could be the reason? Thanks so much again.

Comment: Are there any NA values in `daily_return`? This would cause `prod` to return `NA`. See my updated answer for a fix.

Comment: Note that missing data will bias the annual returns unless the data are missing because the market was closed on that day or the stock's value was unchanged for some other reason.

Comment: Yes it was the missing data. When I removed the missing values and ran it it worked fine. Thanks again!